# get updated list elements after each click with selenium/python

Tags: python, list, selenium

Im trying to click on list elements in an unordered list.
It works fine for the first element, but once the loops goes into the second round I get this error message:

`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

this is my loop:

```
catlist=["Buy & Sell", "Books", "Textbooks"]


for r in range(0,len(catlist)):

                categoryList = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'categoryList-')]")
                avilableButtons=categoryList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

                for text in avilableButtons:
                    if text.text == catlist[r] :
                    text.click()
                    print (r)
```

the category list is being replaced/updated(not sure what the correct phrase is here) with each selection (click) that has been made. so after each click I only find one unordered list named "categoryList-".
I tried using `browser.implicitly_wait(10)` to give it time but the issue remains the same.

Html relevant code:

this is the code before clicking the Buy&sell button.

```
<ul class="categoryList-3073244717">
        <li class="categoryListItem-3726364752">
                <button class="categoryButton-3830788057 button-1997310527 button__medium-1066667140">
                        <h5 class="categoryName-958974558 level1Category-2680817441">Buy &amp; Sell</h5>
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryListItem-3726364752">
                <button class="categoryButton-3830788057 button-1997310527 button__medium-1066667140">
                        <h5 class="categoryName-958974558 level1Category-2680817441">Cars &amp; Vehicles</h5>
                </button>
        </li>
```

after `.click()` the list from above is invisible/gone and I get the subcategory list.

```
<ul class="categoryList-3073244717">
        <li class="categoryListItem-3726364752">
                <button class="categoryButton-3830788057 button-1997310527 button__medium-1066667140">
                        <h5 class="categoryName-958974558 level2Category-867177555">Arts &amp; Collectibles</h5>
                        <svg class="icon-459822882 actionIcon-2308908423" focusable="false" height="100%" role="img" width="100%">
                                <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow-right"></use>
                        </svg>
                </button>
        </li>
        <li class="categoryListItem-3726364752">
                <button class="categoryButton-3830788057 button-1997310527 button__medium-1066667140">
                        <h5 class="categoryName-958974558 level2Category-867177555">Books</h5>
                </button>
        </li>
```

the website Kijiji.ca which is basically like craiglist.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I added  more information's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this blog post after some more searching and asking google the right questions. http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.com/2012/06/staleelementexception.html

This describes the same issue, now with the added loop and try/except statement it works!

```
categoryToPost=["Buy & Sell", "Books", "Textbooks"]
attempts=0

for r in range(0,len(categoryToPost)):

    while attempts <2:
        categoryList = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@class, 'categoryList-')]")
        availableButtons = categoryList.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
        try:
            for text in availableButtons:
                if text.text==categoryToPost[r]:
                    print (text.text)
                    text.click()
                    attempts=0

        except EC.StaleElementReferenceException:

            attempts+=1
            break
```